# Working around evaluation time discrepancy in generators

Tags: python, generator

I found myself running into the gotcha under 'evaluation time discrepancy' from [this list](https://sopython.com/wiki/Common_Gotchas_In_Python) today, and am having a hard time working around it.

As a short demonstration of my problem, I make infinite generators that skip every `n`th number, with `n` going from `[2..5]`:

```
from itertools import count

skip_lists = []
for idx in range(2, 5):
    # skip every 2nd, 3rd, 4th.. number
    skip_lists.append(x for x in count() if (x % idx) != 0)

# print first 10 numbers of every skip_list
for skip_list in skip_lists:
    for _, num in zip(range(10), skip_list):
        print("{}, ".format(num), end="")
    print()
```

Expected output:

```
1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 
1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 
1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13,
```

Actual output:

```
1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, 
1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, 
1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13,
```

---

Once I remembered that great feature, I tried to "solve" it by binding the `if` clause variable to a constant that would be part of the `skip_list`:

```
from itertools import count

skip_lists = []
for idx in range(2, 5):
    # bind the skip distance
    skip_lists.append([idx])
    # same as in the first try, but use bound value instead of 'idx' 
    skip_lists[-1].append(x for x in count() if (x % skip_lists[-1][0]) != 0)

# print first 10 numbers of every skip_list
for skip_list in (entry[1] for entry in skip_lists):
    for _, num in zip(range(10), skip_list):
        print("{}, ".format(num), end="")
    print()
```

But again:

```
1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, 
1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, 
1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13,
```

Apart from an actual solution, I would also love to learn why my hack didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `idx` is never looked up until you start iterating on the  generators (generators are evaluated lazily), at which point `idx = 4` the latest iteratee value, is what is present in the module scope.

You can make each appended generator stateful in `idx` by passing `idx` to a function and reading the value from the function scope at each generator's evaluation time. This exploits the fact that the iterable source of a generator expression is evaluated at the gen. exp's creation time, so the function is called at each iteration of the loop, and `idx` is *safely* stored away in the function scope:

```
from itertools import count

skip_lists = []

def skip_count(skip):
  return (x for x in count() if (x % skip) != 0)


for idx in range(2, 5):
    # skip every 2nd, 3rd, 4th.. number
    skip_lists.append(skip_count(idx))
```

---

Illustration of generator expression's iterable source evaluation at gen. exp's creation:

```
>>> (i for i in 5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Your case is a bit trickier since the exclusions are actually done in a *filter* which is not evaluated at the gen exp's creation time:

```
>>> (i for i in range(2) if i in 5)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x109a0da50>
```

The more reason why the *for* loop and filter all need to be moved into a scope that stores `idx`; not just the filter.

---

On a different note, you can use `itertools.islice` instead of the inefficient logic you're using to print a *slice* of the generator expressions:

```
from itertools import islice

for skip_list in skip_lists:
    for num in islice(skip_list, 10):
        print("{}, ".format(num), end="")
    print()
```

Comment: Great answer, my code works now =) But I am afraid I still don't understand why storing `idx` at `skip_lists.append([idx])` and accessing that instead of `idx` doesn't work. That value doesn't change to the last iteration, `print(skip_list)` yields `[[2, <gen..>], [3, <gen..>], [4, <gen..>]]` for the second example after all.

Comment: The generator expression's code object reads from the name `idx` at the time you're evaluating, which is after first the loop has completed. More like printing `idx` after that loop. The name `idx` at that point reference the int 4.

Comment: That is horrible. Not even `skip_lists.append([lambda x=idx: x])` works to create a locally scoped reference. Thanks for showing me how to solve this.

Comment: It isn't horrible. That's what laziness costs. And I think in the other case, the lambda functions appended should have different `idx` bound values.

Comment: Correction then: I would have an easier time understanding lazy evaluation in python if there was a straight forward way to do scoping, i.e. one that doesn't include using a function to scope.
I don't understand your second comment. With the lambda, `skip_lists[x][0]()` yields `2, 3, 4` respectively. But when the generator calls it, it's apparently still `4, 4, 4`